# jira createmeta not showing all customfields

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

If I navigate to /rest/api/2/issue/createmeta/*PROJ*/issuetype/*N* (in this case, I'm getting Task), the list of fields returned is incomplete.  There are a number of customfields that are in use (I can see them both in the tickets themselves, and also in /plugins/servlet/project-config/*PROJ*/fields ) that are in the createmeta data.

I'm really trying to do this in python jira, where I'm using "expand='projects.issuetypes.fields'" in the createmeta() call, but I figured I'd double-check the results in the rest API directly, and I'm getting the same results there, too.

This is happening in jira 8.20.7.

Essentially, what I'm trying to do, is to programatically get a name/id mapping of all fields in the ticket type.  I'm having far more difficulty doing that than I thought there would be.  I would do it based on /rest/api/2/field but the jira admins have allowed some duplicated names...

EDIT: I realized that it might be worth noting that some of the fields I'm looking for are coming from a ServiceDesk form, although, as far as I can tell, there's no way to determine that, since one of the missing fields contains the name of the form.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using createmeta endpoint?

Instead of that, in order to get all of the customfields and their values; just note their id and get the values from `/rest/api/2/issue/{issueKey}` endpoint.

When you send a `GET` request to `/rest/api/2/issue/{issueKey}` endpoint, you will get a JSON object which contains "`fields`" object in it.

And using the "**fields**" you can determine all of the values that include system fields (description, assignee, etc.) and custom fields (like `customfield_<customfieldid>`).

And for a general approach, you may want to look at the [field types](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/rest-apis/#field-input-formats) in that response.

Comment: An excellent question!  Unfortunately, because my code needs to run against multiple jira instances (don't ask, that's WAY above my pay grade, as it were), I'm having to refer to fields by name, rather than customfield id, since the names are consistent across those instances.  

So, I'm looking for different options to get name/cf mappings.  As I said above, the jira admins allowed duplicate names, so I'm a bit hosed there.  createmeta seemed like it might be useful, but the data is mysteriously incomplete.

Comment: Oh, in Jira, theoretically, you can create lots of fields with same or different types with same name. So, using names may be a fragile method to use; especially if you are not the admin. You may use a static mapping (from db or somewhere else) and tell the admin that "you should also add the field here with its map". Or you may try to use field's description on one Jira instance: you (or admin) can manually add the other jira's mapping field's id to the description of custom field of the first instance.

Comment: Aha!  Thank you.  It took me a while, but this makes sense now.  I see that I won't be able to do a full-on generic-by-name in the direction I was hoping for, because jira doesn't work that way.  One issue type might use a text field (cf_11111) for "dingus" and one might use a dropdown (cf_22222).  I have to know that and take care of that mapping in my code.  I cannot interrogate jira in hopes of finding that out, at least not in a sensible way.  By the same token, there could be 5 different customfields with the name "summary" none of which have anything to do with the system field.

Comment: Great! But sometimes 5 may not enough. Consider that also when creating your structure. Please, don't hesitate to upvote my answer if it helps you.